# Уведомления, зависящие от времени, telegram бота(telebot)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня интересный вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы telegram bot(библиотека telebot) отправлял конкретное уведомление в конкретное время(они хранятся в словаре (ключ:значение - время:текст сообщения)), если таких пар несколько

Comment: Слышали про библиотеку datetime? Там есть datetime.now(); записываете в переменную(now), а потом сверяете: if now. strftime("%H:%M:%S") == 12:00:00: bot.send_message()…